# Questions marked as duplicate in Reopen review queue need to show the question that was duplicated

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, duplicate-questions

I'm busy going through my Reopen review queue and I see most questions so far were closed as duplicates.

I don't feel that I can make an informed decision on whether or not the question has been edited enough or is naturally far enough diverged from the original which it duplicates unless I see the duplicated question as well.

For that reason, might I suggest a side-by-side of the question... in question? lol ... and the question that was marked as the one that was duplicated?

Something akin to the way edit approvals are presented when in review would be perfect.

Comment: It is just the nature of the beast, you *always* have to look at the complete Q+A to properly review.  The only way you can see any posted answers for example, the most dominant factor to determine which is the correct dup.

Comment: I agree with Hans here. There is not enough screen to fit everything you need in one view and that becomes more true if there have been two or more duplicates.

Comment: @rene: Not everyone has "enough screen" but you also cannot say that everyone has "not enough screen".  Since we don't need multiple copies of the sidebar, a 4k screen can fit 3-4 of the SO's configured maximum text width (less if you are scaling, but a 4k screen running with 2:1 scaling really counts as a 2k screen).

Comment: @BenVoigt it might be a nice userscript project ...

Comment: This is a good premise with a bad solution.

Comment: good idea or not, this won't be implemented. But winter hats will be on time on 01/12/2018.